# Why does an external SVG extend beyond the confines of a parent SVG's viewbox?

Tags: html, svg

I'm building a web app which uses SVG to both position and display certain elements. The purpose is to allowing zooming and panning/scanning on an externally linked SVG image. On Opera, Firefox and Chrome (all latest GAs) everything works as expected. On IE and Edge (also latest GAs) the image extends beyond the confines of the parent SVG when I up the scaling.

I've tried various options including explicitly setting CSS overflows to hidden and tweaking the viewBox settings both in the external SVG and my inline SVGs.

I've isolated all the relevant HTML, CSS and SVG data and included in an example hosted here: https://svgexample.azurewebsites.net/

The external SVG is linked in the code. The following details the structure:

Orange colour: Body background colour.
Green: A container for the content I want to be displayed.
Blue: A container for the image (this should be where the zoomed image is confined)
Red: A single rectangle representing the external SVG.

The external SVG is not my actual image, I've included a placeholder for simplicity. The effect is identical with the rectangle and the real image.

Correct appearance is visible in latest GA versions of Opera, Chrome and Firefox. Incorrect appearance in IE and Edge.

**EDIT**

I've added the inline elements to CodePen https://codepen.io/cahunter/pen/EqYrpP. Of course the external SVG (containing the red `<rect>` element) is still external, linked to maintain consistency with my requirement.

Comment: Still no other replies? Hope someone has some pointers here! I've tried nesting the SVG inline (rather than external) and it doesn't suffer the same problem. I'm now questioning if this is related to Microsoft's implementation of the SVG `<image>` tag when rendering overflow in relation to external sources.

Would love if someone's encountered something similar and has a recommendation to make.

Answer (score 0):

overflow is not an [inherited property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) so you'd need to set overflow to hidden on the `<svg>` element itself rather than on an ancestor.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Robert, but I've tried setting overflow="hidden" and style="overflow: hidden;" on every `<svg>` and `<g>` element in the tree (incuding the external SVG) as well as the`<image>` element.

I've also considered that the external SVG may have been cached so I forced a hard refresh. I still have this issue in IE and Edge.

I've also tried